# Header text outside header DIV

Tags: html, css, header

Would you know why the text "Text on the left" and "Text on the right", supposed to be within my header blue DIV are under it? Looks like there's some unexpected padding or something to the top of the text. [JS Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Grek/bZsck/).

[image: header text]

CSS:

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 18px;
    background: #0064C5;
}
#header p.left {
    float:left;
    color:#000;
}

#header p.right {
    float:right;
    color:#000;
}
```

Comment: Show the HTML for those text pieces

Comment: Did you use a CSS reset?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its the default margin on the `<p>` just add `margin: 0;` to `#header p.left`

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Humility/bZsck/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Add margin: 0 to #header p

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 18px;
    background: #0064C5;
    clear: both;
}
#header p { margin:0;}
#header p.left {
    float:left;
    color:#000;

}

#header p.right {
    float:right;
    color:#000;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply remove the `float:left;` in `#header p.lef`t

Try this code

```
#header p.left {
    color:#000;
}
```

Instead of

```
#header p.left {
    float:left;
    color:#000;
}
```

See this design : http://jsfiddle.net/Grek/bZsck/

Answer (score 0):

Because header have fixed height.

```
#header {
width: 100%;
overflow:hidden;
background: #0064C5;}
```

Remove height, add overflow (because header.p have float);